# Embedded content is not displayed; GoogleDocs viewer returns 204

Tags: google-docs, embedly

I use the card format Embedly. However, depending on the content I'm embedding, the Google Docs viewer returns a 204 status code and displays empty content.

Is there any way to avoid this?